# Android BroadcastReceiver firing with delay upon notification action click

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-background, notification-action

I am trying to run a Retry routine upon notification action click, for this, I have created a `BroadcastReceiver` and also registered it in the `AndroidManifest` file.

While creating the notification with action I am using `PendingIntent` and setting that pending intent with the notification action.

When the app is running or in the background (not removed from the recent apps list) then the broadcast receiver is received instantly upon clicking the notification action. But after killing the app (removing it from the recent app list) the broadcast receiver takes some to fire.

Below are the code snippets for different components.

AndroidManifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver.RetryStatusBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```

Broadcast receiver

```
public class RetryStatusBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
    }
}
```

Notification firing code

```
Intent retryIntent = new Intent(this, RetryStatusBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent retryPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), uniqueId + 1, retryIntent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Action retryAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_retry, "Retry", retryPendingIntent);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.background_syncing_notification_channel_id))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationMessage)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationMessage))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
        .addAction(retryAction);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(activityPendingIntent);
notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (notificationManager != null) {
    notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I have also tried extending my BroadcastReceiver from `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` but the result is the same.
I have also tried removing `android:enabled` and `android:exported` tags but nothing seems to work here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any update on this?

Comment: @AnkitChandora no luck so far, moved on to some other task.